# Resharper 2016.3.1 not running MSTest in VS 2017 RC

Tags: mstest, visual-studio-2017, resharper-2016

I can not to run MsTest unit tests in visual studio 2017 RC using resharper 2016.3.

I select run test in drop-down menu, but resharper not show progress running in Unit Test Session Window.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: submit it in jetbrain tracker if you think this is a bug

Answer (score 0):

According to the JB site, R# unit testing assistance in ASP.NET Core and .NET Core projects will not work with visual studio 2017 RC. Unclear if this applies to you though.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Unit_Testing__Index.html

Comment: Note for other reviewers: this answer is not link-only; the main points of the link are summarized in the answer.